# Plot a function in polar coordinates: $r=a(1+b\cos\varphi)$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

> Plot a function in polar coordinates (consider parameters positive): $$r=a(1+b\cos\varphi).$$
>
> [(Image that replaced the text).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzL0G.png)

Can you help me with general way/algorithm of solving that kind of tasks? What kind of steps do I need to do function research?

Comment: Is it expected that you should do this) or consider how to do it) without graphing software? It may be, because that could be regarded as a worthwhile exercise - but I feel like I should point out that there are free options on the internet that will do these sorts of things for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a series of values of $\varphi$ from $\varphi=0$ to $2\pi$ , plot each point computed with $r=a(1+b\cos(\varphi))\:;\:x=r\cos(\varphi) \:,\: y=r\sin(\varphi)$.

[image]